# php session doesn't work in safari

Tags: php, session, safari

I have a simple login page. Everything works fine in Mozilla and IE. When I try to login in Safari, the session is empty, just a white page. If i check the session id, it gives me the id, but shows nothing else.
`echo session_id();` 
If I copy the page URL and then go to another page, and paste the URL, the browser shows the page.If I refresh it, it disappears again.(but it always shows the session id)
Everything works in Mozilla and IE.

update: Thank you all for your help, yes, it was something on the page, I tried a simple page and it worked. Learned my lesson. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sessions in php use a session cookie, so check this:

- is your safari browser allowing cookies?, by default the session cookie it's called "phpsessionid"
- are you sure that you used a "session_start()"? (and its better if you use a "session_name()" too)

i hope this helps

Comment: Safari shows me all the cookies, I used "session_name()", it shows it too. But no changes, when I copy and paste the URL, it gives me the same session id and shows the page. When I refresh it, it disappears again.

Comment: well then.. @Col. Shrapnel is right, you have to check if the id is the same.. and debug your code.. test with a simple page, try to find out what's wrong, if you pout your page online maybe we could test it

Answer (score 0):

Just check Safari's cookie policy.
It looks like your browser just do not send a session id  cookie back.

> If i check the session id, it gives me the id

It is not session id itself what ou have to check.
But rather **if session id is the same as before**

if it's the same, there is something with your code.
You have to start to debug it.
Start from running a test file with this code:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter']=0;
echo "Counter ".$_SESSION['counter']++." раз.<br>
<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.session_name().'='.session_id().">reload</a>";
```

if it works, make it

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter']=0;
echo "Counter ".$_SESSION['counter']++." раз.<br>
<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].">reload</a>";
```

and find a way to watch an HTTP interchange protocol. That's most important thing - to see what cookies going from server and back. I know no tool for safari but there is ought to be one

Comment: Yes, it's the same exact id. In my safari settings in "Accept cookies" it says "always"

Comment: @Tamara well you have to debug your code. if it's the same id, its NOT a technology issue but code issue. You have to debug it